# PDO Exception could not find driver

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, pdo, mamp

I know this question have been asked a thousand of times, but I can't find a solution. I'm running **Symfony 2** with a **PostgreSql** database (php running in MAMP, and PG DB on an another port and install).

I was running well (could have install the DB using the app/console create cmd) however now I can't use it anymore for updating the schema. Got the error :

```
PDO Exception, could not find driver error
```

I tried everything:

- Php.ini verification : OK
- using the same in the `CLI` and `phpInfo();`
- PDO verification in phpInfo : drivers enabled for pgSQL mySQL etc...
- Restart Mamp + OSX apache server : OK

Comment: CLI and Apache SAPI are two distinct binaries and config files.

Comment: Can you post the output of `var_dump(pdo_drivers());` ?

Comment: The php.ini you edit might not be the one actually read by the server. Create a `phpinfo()` page to state the one used by your PHP installation.

Comment: var_dump(pdo_drivers()) : 

array(3) { [0]=> string(6) "sqlite" [1]=> string(5) "pgsql" [2]=> string(5) "mysql" }

Looks like the config used by the apache contains pgsql...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution,
I just made an alias in my .bash_profile to the php used by the server to be sure that the CLI will use the good one.

## Alias PHP -> Mamp CLI

alias phpmamp='/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/bin/php'

Now it works.

Comment: Well done. Suggest you click on "accept" for this answer to finalize your work.